# JPA Consulta Clave valor con IN

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Tengo esta consulta donde tengo que pasar una lista y decir si existe. La cuestión es para el uso de IN en bus tiene que ir delante o detrás? Si es detrás porque motivo?

```
boolean existsByUserAndBusInAndCar(String User, List<String> bus, Car car);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo mejore en estos casos es verificar la documentación de la sintaxis para la creación de consultas con `spring-data`, te agrego el link de la documentación:

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Como puedes ver según el ejemplo `findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages)` la clausula `IN` se ubica después del campo.